# Angular quick start won't start

Tags: angular

I downloaded the Angular Quick start project from here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html.  The sample won't start on my linux machine.  node.js and npm are at the specified version levels according to the README.md file.  I have node.js installed in a local home directory and have added it to my path.   I've run the npm install serveral times and get the same result.  As a side note, I was able to install and run the quick start project on my MAC.

Here's the output:

```
npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start /home/mydir/quickstart-master
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

[0] tsc: Command not found.
[0] tsc -w exited with code 1
[1] lite-server: Command not found.
[1] lite-server exited with code 1

npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/home/mydir/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/mydir/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mydir/quickstart-master/npm-debug.log
```

OK, so I ran the suggested command: npm i tsc lite-server and am now getting this error:

```
 npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start /home/mydir/quickstart-master
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'moduleResolution'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'lib'.

npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/home/mydir/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/mydir/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mydir/quickstart-master/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `tsc` and `lite-server` installed and they do not appear under the dependencies in the package.json.

Run

```
npm i tsc lite-server
```

Then start the app again

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "start" script in the `package.json` file.

From:

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
```

To:

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

And then re-run `npm start`.

I don't know why this is necessary, but I ran into this problem too.  Looks like it was changed back in April for some reason: [diff for package.json](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/commit/c18870fb02801c395bdba53e9d18cc7877c14fed#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2).